# integrating Outlook with c#

Tags: c#, outlook

is it possible to integrate outlook with my c# program without having Microsoft office installed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what functionality you are trying to achieve?
It also depends on your environment.Do you have access to exchange server?
For example, If you want to create appointments in outlook client for individual user, you can very well make use of webservice provided by Exchange server. However, it works starting with outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. If you want to call an Outlook dll you will need Outlook installed.

Perhaps if you describe what you need to do there may be an alternative approach, such as calling Exchange Server as suggested by Edwin.

Comment: i want to send outlook tasks from my application.